# How to force users to a local page but then allow them to continue browsing

Tags: dns, redirection, openwrt

We have an internal web server on our local network, which serves as a notice board. Sometimes we want to use this to make urgent announcements. In these cases we would like to redirect each user's next "click" to the noticeboard, but allow users to continue browsing after viewing it. So for each user, the first request they make after the setting is applied would be redirected, but subsequent requests would not be.

Is there a way to do this with openwrt?

Edit: This is similar to what a captive portal does, but I don't think a captive portal is what we want. Firstly, captive portal is a WiFi concept, and works on an access point. This network has a central openwrt router, but many access points, and I'd like to configure it centrally if possible. Also, captive portal forces you to a page when you first connect, but I want to force people onto the notice board on their next click, even if they are already connected.

Edit 2: Actually it seems I was wrong about captive portal being a WiFi-only concept; however, all the  examples I have found relate to guest WiFi hotspots. I guess what I'm looking for is indeed a captive portal, but one that can be applied centrally, and which "captivates" users who are connected via cable as well as WiFi, and those who are already connected as well as new ones attempting to connect.

Comment: You need a Captive Portal.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think so. I've edited my question to clarify